# Set headers after countdown timer expires

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a countdown timer that counts from 10 down to 0. I want to set new headers after the countdown timer expires...

```
   var timeleft = 10;
   var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
       document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;
       timeleft -= 1;

       if(timeleft <= -2){
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "0"
       }
   }, 1000);
```

Any one knows the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: How about calling a function to setHeaders at point where timeLeft <= 2

Comment: ```if(timeleft == 0)``` doesn't work for me. It stops at 1 then jumps to 0. That's why i shifted it to the negative timing. and it worked

Comment: Either decrement `timeleft` as the first step of the anonymous function, or as the last step.  But in the middle it's just confusing you.  What does this have to do with PHP headers?  You'll have to do ajax or submit something to get back to PHP.

Comment: Okay, how do I refresh page and redirect to the real file with ajax (After the countdown finishes)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to add a new element (like `<h1>`) to your page, then try it:

```
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;

    if (timeleft == 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "0";

        // create new h1 element
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.innerHTML = "Your header text";

        // and here append it to the page before the timer
        var timer = document.getElementById("countdown");
        var parent = timer.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(h1, timer);
    }

    timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

Or if you already have a header, and you just want to set new text to it, then at point "// create new h1 element" just get the existing one by id and set innerHTML to it:

```
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Your new header text";
```

Hopefully, it helped :)

Comment: I mean ```php header();``` not ```<h1></h1>```

Comment: I think it could help you then! [https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest

Comment: It's great, I'm happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(
      function(){

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;

        if(timeleft <= 0){

          clearInterval(downloadTimer);
          document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "0";

          // jump_to_your_next_function() or
          clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        }
        timeleft -= 1;
      }, 1000
    );
```